# Romex cable tidying in basement

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement, joists

Old house, crazy town in the basement in regards to wiring. I'd like to clean it up a little, at least visually - happy to get contractor out if needed - but not sure what to ask for. So what would be my options for for this? Vast majority of wiring is attached to joists with electrical staples.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Neatness does count, but what will you do if you have slack? Or, worse, what if you do if a cable is 6" short for the cleanup? (What is this worth to you?)

Comment: If you think that cabling is messy, you would be disgusted by some of the cabling I've seen. My opinion: Let it be.

Comment: bundle the low voltage stuff together using quick ties

Comment: I agree with @JonathonReinhart....I wish my basement wiring was this "sloppy".. :(

Comment: Thanks - this is good feedback! If it's "okay" by experienced standards, this is great to know! I think bundling (or removing used) low voltage cables is a good idea too. I'll leave the romex as is.

Answer (score 2):

I cleaned up the wires in my basement by removing the ones that were no longer being used for anything--old phone wires, TV cables, doorbells, even a security system that had been removed years ago.  This removed about half the wires I had. 
It looks like some of yours could be similar.  Then, if you have some wires that aren't stapled up nicely and are droopy, you can fasten them to well-secured wires with cable ties.

Comment: Thanks! Yes - the cat 5 is not used (AFAIK), and the thin white wires are from the old security system. I think these can be removed safely.

Answer (score 1):

The sloppiest wires in your picture (the ones hanging down low) look like coaxial cable lines and cat 5 networking wires. Not sure how *neat* you want the end result to be, but you could certainly clean up the mounting of those low voltage wires. If they are going underneath joists, make small holes in the center of the joist to route them through.  This won't cost you anything (if you do it) or much (if you hire a handyman).